# What does Make To Last mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "made to last" means in this sentence: made to last since nineteen eighty two?

Comment: Confusingly, this has nothing to do with 'lasting since 1982'. A paraphrase is 'We've been making these since 1982, and they're made to last'. Here, 'to' conveys the sense 'in such a way that they will normally' [last] [a long time].

Comment: There is a subtle difference between this question and the one it was marked a duplicate of. The answer to this one (from the context) is that it has to do with an item manufactured to last a long time. (The answer to the other one is that at some point—either when manufactured, upgraded, or repaired—something was modified to last a long time. It could be an item, or something less tangible—like marriage.) Funnily, if the company shut down in 1982, then the items it made really could have been made to last since that year. (But that's highly unlikely.)

Answer (score 1):

It means it is of good quality, so that it would last a long time before it breaks.